# How to declare a constructor in a subclass when the superClass does not have a constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to implement a constructor for a subclass, however I keep getting `"error: class, interface, or enum expected"` when I compile.

My code for the overall looks like this:

```
public class Super{
    //methods go here, no constructor.
}
```

Here is what I tried but it did not work:

```
public class Sub extends Super{
    private boolean myCondition;
    public Sub(boolean condition){
        super();
        myCondition = condition;
    }
}
```

I would assume that I would not need to call super() in the subs constructor as the compiler should implicitly call it.

Thanks.

Comment: Even if you don't define a constructor, the class still gets a default constructor, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: `however I keep getting "error: class, interface, or enum expected" when I compile.` And where? Code is fine and should compile.

Comment: when I remove/comment out the constructor in my sub the java file of the class compiles, which is not the case when I add it.

Comment: Ok nevermind I am just stupid, I had a "}" placed in a location it was not supposed to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every class has a constructor. If you do not specify one, you get a default constructor.  [JLS-8.8.9 Default Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is implicitly declared.
>
> If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the default constructor has an empty body. Otherwise, the default constructor simply invokes the superclass constructor with no arguments.
>
> It is a compile-time error if a default constructor is implicitly declared but the superclass does not have an accessible constructor (§6.6) that takes no arguments and has no throws clause.
>
> In a class type, if the class is declared public, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier public (§6.6); if the class is declared protected, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier protected (§6.6); if the class is declared private, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier private (§6.6); otherwise, the default constructor has the default access implied by no access modifier.

So `Super` (a `public` class) has a default constructor inserted by the compiler that looks something like

```
public Super() {
  super();
}
```